# Static variable initialisation

Tags: java

Are static variables initialised every time a new instance of the object containing these variables are created ? Or are they initialised just once when the object is first called?

Comment: What do you mean by "instance static variables"? That's like talking about "String int variables".

Comment: there's no such thing as instance static variable. You either have an instance variable or static (class) variable!

Comment: And you don't call an object either - only methods on it.

Comment: You cant talk about initialization of a class when you are talking about static variables. These variables are loaded when the class is loaded

Comment: @user470184: just a suggestion -- that you edit your question to get rid of "instance static" and change it to just "static". You'll probably lose the negative votes on the question if you do this (I know you'll lose mine).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You said

**Are instance static variables initialised**...

stop right there, the statement makes no sense.  static variables live on the class, not on any particular instance.  They are initialized in an initialization procedure that is run when an instance is created, a static method on the class is run, or a static variable on the class is accessed. (Full disclosure, @Bruno's answer led me to this information).

Comment: Class loading != class initialization.

Comment: @bruno "What the compiler actually does is to internally produce a single class initialization routine that combines all the static variable initializers and all of the static initializer blocks of code, in the order that they appear in the class declaration.  This single initialization procedure is run automatically, one time only, when the class is first loaded." from Java in a Nutshell

Comment: hvgotcodes, don't believe books. **This is simply wrong**. Go check the VM Spec sections 2.17.4 and 2.17.5 (links in my answer below). A class is NOT initialized when it is loaded. And a class can be loaded multiple times, and initialized multiple times, if you use multiple class loaders.

Comment: @bruno, ok i agree. ;)  If you want me to delete my edit so you can use it let me know

Answer (score 3):

Static fields are initialized during the **initialization** of the class (don't mix *initialization* and *loading*, they are different things --  a class can be loaded, and you can do reflection on it, without ever initializing it).

Also, class initialization can happen more than once for a given class if you are using multiple `ClassLoader`s.

See VM Spec [section 2.17.4, Initialization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#19075), and [section 2.17.5, Detailed initialization procedure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#24237) for more details on when exactly a class will be loaded and when exactly it will be initialized..

**EDIT**: trivial example that will show how a class can be loaded *and* initialized multiple times and that loading does not automatically imply initialization:

```
public class A { static { System.out.println("I've been initialized!"); } }
public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(..., null);
    System.out.println("loading...");
    Class<?> aClass = cl.loadClass("A");
    // here you could perform reflection on aClass, without initializing it
    System.out.println("Will be initialized now:");
    Object o = aClass.newInstance();
    System.out.println("Let's load once again...");
    ClassLoader cl2 = new URLClassLoader(..., null);
    Class<?> aClass2 = cl2.loadClass("A");
    System.out.println("Will be initialized a second time:");
    Object o2 = aClass2.newInstance();

    // the following is false:
    System.out.println("aClass1.equals(aClass2) = " + aClass1.equals(aClass2));

    // the following is true:
    System.out.println("aClass1.getName().equals(aClass2.getName())" + aClass1.getName().equals(aClass2.getName()));
  }
}
```

(I hope this compiles when you specify the missing `URL[]` object in the URLClassLoader's constructor...)

Note that it is necessary to set the class loaders' parents `null`, otherwise their parents would be the main application class loader (ie, the same that loaded the class `Main`), then because Java delegates the loading to the parent class loader first by default, if the class `A` is in the class path, you would see the load and initialization only once.

Finally, note that `Class.load("A")` is not equivalent to `classLoader.loadClass("A")`. If you check the documentation of `Class.load(String)`, you will see that this method loads *and* initializes the class. There's an overload of `Class.load(...)` that takes a boolean indicating if it should initialize the class or not.

Comment: can a class be initialized many times?  A line in section 2.17.5 reads "If the class or interface has already been initialized, then no further action is required. Release the lock on the Class object and complete normally."

Comment: Yes. In runtime, a class is identified by the tuple (ClassLoader, Package, Name). If you use 2 different, unrelated class loaders, you will have 2 *different* classes (with the same name, so that their respective Class objects are !c1.equals(c2), but c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()) is true), so the initialization procedure can occur once for each.